# Preserve View State in Vaadin only in specific cases

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14

So, I have a view which should preserve the state when a user reloads. This is easy to do and well documented. However, in one case I reload the page from the server side after the user performs a specific action in which case I would actually want the view to completely reload.

Is there a way to differentiate between those cases and influence when the view should preserve its state?

Comment: Which Vaadin version you use? The answer is different for Vaadin 8 and 14 for example.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm using Vaadin 14

Comment: It would also help, if you could be a bit more explicit: how do you
preserve the state right now?  What have you tried to _not_ preserve it?

Comment: @cfrick Of course, sorry: I followed this [article](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-preserving-state-on-refresh) on how to preserve the state and it worked as intended. 
As for what I did to not preserve it: Nothing, because I don't know how. I wasn't able to find any solutions/tips online and I'm not very experienced with Vaadin.

Comment: Might it make sense to have two separate Views - let's call them "PreservingView" and "RegularView" - so that if you actually want to completely reload, you'll redirect to "RegularView" and otherwise you'll stick to "PreservingView"?

Comment: @ollitietavainen That would be an option, yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In Vaadin 14 you can annotate specific [views / components](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-preserving-state-on-refresh/#preserving-the-state-of-a-component) with `@PreserveOnRefresh` annotation. So if you have two views in your app like following, the `RegularView` will not be refreshed on reload.

```
@Route("preserve")
@PreserveOnRefresh
public class PreservedView extends VerticalLayout {

    public PreservedView() {
        // ...
    }
}

@Route("regular")
public class RegularView extends VerticalLayout {

    public RegularView () {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Originally I wanted to avoid this as to not introduce an extra view in an already bloated app, but as it seems there is no other way to solving this. Thanks!